# update entity value GAE with python

Tags: google-app-engine

```
class UserData(db.Model):
    user_name = db.StringProperty()
    pass_word = db.StringProperty() 
    points = db.IntegerProperty()
```

what if I wanted to update "points" entity? Read google docs, found no luck.

Comment: There is no points entity.  Work on the reading comprehension first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you searched/read the docs very hard.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Python_Datastore_API

Gives a discussion on how to use and create/update entities.

Also the basic API docs goes into detail

The model class docs even tell you

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass